# How to remove hidden fields from export to excel in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have total 20 columns in my ag grid out of 20 columns 5 columns are hidden ,here my problem is when i try to export to excel then all hidden fields also exporting ,how to avid hidden fields from export to excel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass param object containing visible columns like -

```
const visibleColumns = this.gridColumnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns();
const params = { columnKeys : visibleColumns};
this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel(params);
```

From docs  -

> **getAllDisplayedColumns()**
>     Returns all columns currently displayed (e.g. are visible and if in a group, the group is showing
>   the columns)